# Just trying to set up a puppet client and server in CentOS VMs from scratch - basic setup problems

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos, ssl, puppet

I have a set of two VM's which I am trying to use puppet on.
It's about a simple setup as you  can get, I am trying to setup a server and setup a client and simply get to writing some puppet policy.

I am using a fresh install of CentOS on the client and the server.
I am using the EPEL repos.
I tried following the following guide:
http://www.how-to-linux.com/2009/02/how-to-install-a-puppet-master-and-client-server-on-centos-52/
I have also referenced the puppet documentation

Server
I set the hostname to puppet.apt15 in `/etc/sysconfig/`
I set the ips for both client and server (in both the client and server) `/etc/hosts`

```
192.168.2.5             puppet
192.168.2.4             puppet-db
127.0.0.1               localhost.localdomain localhost
::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
```

I have tried several combinations including the apt15 and not including it. I have reinstalled everything from scratch on both twice.
This is the error I get:

```
[root@puppet-db ~]# puppetd --test
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
info: Caching certificate for puppet-db.apt15
err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: certificate verify failed
warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
err: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

I have installed ntpd, and run ntpdate on pools.ntp.org on both machines. This was however after the installs and attempts to connect. But I cleared the `/var/lib/puppet.ssl` folders several times on the client and server and ran `puppet-ca --clean :all` on the server. I have also tried the process with `setenforce 0` (SELinux off) and the firewall off

I am at my wits end. Can I turn SSL authentication off so I can just work with writing policy?

I fear something is wrong with my DNS\hostname settings and this is just a basic setup. I don't care about security right now, I just want something I can start working with so I can learn it. I don't have any official domains i.e. something.mysite.com which a lot of other guides seem to assume.

Comment: What, if anything, is in /var/log/messages on the PuppetMaster VM?  That might tell you if the connection is even being made.  Also, what does `puppetca --list --all` show on the PuppetMaster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it,
I did everything from scratch again, but made sure **before** even beginning the tutorial in the article I did the following on the server and client:

```
/etc/hosts
192.168.2.5             puppet-db.apt15 puppet-db
192.168.2.4             puppetmaster.apt15 puppetmaster puppet
127.0.0.1               localhost.localdomain localhost
::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
```

/etc/sysconfig/network 
Set hostname to [server name].apt15

```
yum install ntp
ntpdate pool.ntp.org
ntpd
shutdown -r now (then login)
setenforce 0
```

Then start tutorial
I also had to use puppetd --server myserver.domain.com --waitforcert 60 --test from the documentation instead of the lines in the guide to get the certificate signed and accepted.